# How can I create a setup that installed from command line in install shield 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, installshield, silent-installer

I want to disable the screens in dialog tab, but I also want that the installer doesn't show any screen.

From commandline and install silently.

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.Arguments = "/s /v /qn /min";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = desktopPath + "\\" + "Tabcontrol.exe";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: i want that when setup is being install there is no user interface and installed in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run an installshield setup in silentmode it requires a record file that contains the information the setups needs. It is not really initially silent it's more like unattended and silent.

Here you can find the information how to create this recordfile: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/CreatetheResponseFile.htm

Here you will find everything you need to know about any unattended/silent setup: http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

Comment: Actually when i try to create a response file with /r, it doesn't create any .iss file in %windir% , and only the setup started.

Comment: Response files are applicable to InstallScript projects in the Premier and Professional editions of InstallShield. Express projects (or Basic MSI projects in the Premier or Professional editions) do not create or read response files. Which project type are you using?